# Updating static assets in public folder with Rails3 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a few files in the public folder of my Rails app that aren't part of the asset pipeline (such as sitemap.xml or a .js file for an embedabble widget).

While I have no issues updating the assets in the public/assets folder, I have troubles updating these static files. Strangely, I can add new files, but I can't update existing ones. When I do update them in development, the modifications aren't taken into account on production environment (Heroku).

I have tried many things but can't seem to find a solution. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who might arrive here with the same problem, I ended up getting the solution from Heroku support team. I chose the last option of clearing the cache (Rails.cache.clear) because I had nothing important in Memcachier.

Full response below :

---

> Hello,
>
> I'm Terence from the Ruby Task Force. I've looked into your issue and
>   I believe what is happening is normal and what is expected even if
>   that's not what you want. Let me explain.
>
> The reason you're seeing the old robots.txt is because of rack-cache.
>   You can tell verify by curling the URL.
>
> Notably, there's a X-Rack-Cache header. Even though you deleted
>   public/robots.txt and it doesn't exist in the slug either, since it
>   exists in Rack-Cache via HTTP caching. Rails will skip the entire
>   chain and just return what's in the cache. Tailing the logs you'll see
>   this in the heroku router:
>
> 2017-12-27T03:15:23.870134+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/robots.txt" host=[hidden]
>   request_id=5caea3e9-a665-4b52-b61f-c7ebf210e155 fwd="74.108.35.53"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=576 protocol=https
>
> but you won't see the corresponding logs because of this. You might be
>   able to see more information from interactions with Rack::Cache by
>   setting verbose. I went and tried to deploy your code to a new app and
>   could not reproduce the problem.
>
> To work around this issue, you can try the rack-cache configuration of
>   allow_revalidate:
>
> A boolean specifying whether revalidate requests sent by the client
>   should be honored by the cache. When this option is enabled
>   (rack-cache.allow_revalidate is true), requests that include a
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0 header cause the cache to assume its copy of
>   the response is stale, resulting in a conditional GET / validation
>   request to be sent to the server.
>
> Most browsers include a Cache-Control: max-age=0 header when the user
>   performs a refresh (e.g., clicking the “Refresh” button).
>
> IMPORTANT: Enabling this option globally allows all clients to break
>   your cache.
>
> which should allow you to bust the cache of that page. If that fails
>   you can try clearing the memcache addon through Rails.cache.clear or
>   through Memcachier itself. If you go this route, it will blow
>   everything inside memcache away.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has an immutable file system, meaning you can't make changes to, or additions to the file system. You'll need a different strategy. Serve the files from another service, put them in a db, or link them externally to something like Amazon S3.

But I'm not sure I understand exactly what part of the process you are referring to. Are you talking about files that are generated in a build, or files that are modified during the running of the service?

Comment: For examples I have a sitemap.xml file in my public folder I'd like to make additions to, or a widget.js file in that same folder I'd like to edit. Right now I have to make a new widget2.js file and point to that new file, I can't seem to change widget.js in production.

Comment: What is your development flow? Are you saying that you make changes to your repo (git I assume), then push those changes to Heroku, you don't see the changes when the site starts back up? Are you using Heroku CLI to push or GitHub integration?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm saying - I'm using Heroku CLI

Comment: Are you on the correct branch? By default `git push heroku` pushes the master branch. If you run `git branch` you'll see what branches are available, and which one you're on.

Comment: Yes, I mean everything gets updated fine, except for these existing files in the public folder

Comment: Try this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#the-rails-3-asset-pipeline

Answer (score -1):

The `/public/assets` folder is auto-generated, so you can't insert files into it directly. In fact, this folder should be in your `.gitignore`, which would explain why your changes aren't propagating to production. That is, they're not being included in your commits.

Completely static assets, such as your `sitemap.xml`, should go into the `/public` folder. `js` files and others that are actually part of site execution should go in one of the `/app/assets/javascripts` (for code just for this site), `/lib/assets/javascripts` (for code that you share among your company/projects), `/vendor/assets/javascripts` folders (for code from external sources).

You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks but you did not really answer the question. I am talking indeed about files in the public folder (not public/assets)